# Convert a date with timezone from Backend to user selected timezone in UI

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I am having an api which contains date in the format

```
12/23/2023 at 03:31 a.m. CST
```

I want to convert this to a date with user selected timezone in the following format

```
12/23/2023 at 7:31 p.m.
```

For displaying in UI timezone part not required.

```
const options = {
    timeZone: tzString, //user selected timezone
    day: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "2-digit",
  };

  return Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(new Date(date));
```

I tries this but not getting in correct timezone.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am passing "12/23/2023 at 03:31 a.m. CST" as "date". Is this wrong?. How I need to pass exactly to new Date() for getting date in new timezone.? I will parse based on that @evolutionxbox

Comment: `new Date('12/23/2023 at 03:31 a.m. CST')` will result in `Invalid Date`

Comment: ECMAScript only officially understands [one date format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format).  Anything else is implementation specific.  But also, how would you expect it to know what an ambiguous abbreviation like "CST" means?  It could be Central Standard Time (UTC-6), China Standard Time (UTC+8) or Cuba Standard Time (UTC-5).

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to transform the time from one timezone to another timezones time.

To convert a date to another time zone:

1. Use the **toLocaleString()** method to get a string that represents the date according to the provided time zone.
2. Pass the result to the **Date()** constructor.
3. The returned **Date** object will have its date and time set according to the provided time zone.

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
  }),
); 
// "7/25/2023, 11:32:29 AM"

console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('ca-CA', {
    timeZone: 'Canada/Pacific',
  }),
);
// "25/7/2023 8:32:29"
```

Comment: This does not take into consideration that the asker wants to format _an existing_ datetime, not just format a new one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the asker would, in the code provided above, change the following: 
const date = new Date('23 dec 2023 03:31:00 CST');

Comment: @MilošMilosavljević - The approach you describe a common mistake.  See "Re-Parsing" in the "Common Errors" section of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824